# Remove permissions on django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I wanted to know if something happens if I remove the permissions that are created by default in the database

```
1,'Can add log entry',1,'add_logentry'
2,'Can change log entry',1,'change_logentry'
3,'Can delete log entry',1,'delete_logentry'
4,'Can add permission',2,'add_permission'
5,'Can change permission',2,'change_permission'
6,'Can delete permission',2,'delete_permission'
7,'Can add group',3,'add_group'
8,'Can change group',3,'change_group'
9,'Can delete group',3,'delete_group'
10,'Can add user',4,'add_user'
```

These are some of the permissions that appear in the database when the migration is made, something happens or I delete some of the permissions?

Comment: You can add custom permissions, but I've never seen anyone remove the default permissions. Why don't you just try and find out? If you told us *why* you want to do this, someone might know a different solution to  the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: I thought that because I can not think of doing so that those terms do not come out when a client wants to add permissions to a group, the client is not interested in the token permissions etc.

Comment: That's pretty low level stuff. If the client is technical enough to be trusted to modify permissions, perhaps you don't need to hide the implementation details for them? If this is confusing for them, I would be careful about giving them access to admin pages and let them modify group permissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are default permissions as per [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/default/#default-permissions)

> ### Default permissions
>
> When django.contrib.auth is listed in your INSTALLED_APPS setting, it
>   will ensure that three default permissions – add, change and delete –
>   are created for each Django model defined in one of your installed
>   applications.

You need following for things like Django Admin as it highly relies on following permissions